# Hard drive allocation

Tags: hard-drive

Can I change the amount of hard drive space i have allocated to Ubuntu later after I have installed it? I'm not sure how much I should allocate as I wont be putting many big files on it... How much would you recommend if I have 2TB/Windos7

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Easiest tool to do so I find is gparted, so if you think you need to add more space or you need more space in windows you can do so on the fly.

Just search for 'gparted' in the software center.
If for whatever reason you like using terminal,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Comment: gparted cannot truly make all changes on the fly. It needs to be run from a liveCd in some cases/

Comment: Which is why I always have one on hand :P

Comment: And in all honesty, I never partition while booted from the same disk.  Just too scary for me.  Hence the 'on the fly' comment.